# Check input value, allowing only numeric values with a maximum value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need my code to validate the input, it should allow numeric values only and warn the user otherwise. User should also be notified and input rejected if the value exceeds a given maximum value. Also, it should not allow alphanumeric values

But my code always fire a Javascript error

```
var MaxValue= document.getElementById('MV').value;
if (MaxValue > 9999999) alert('The Max Value entered cannot be more than 10 million. Please verify the value entered.'); 
if (typeof (MaxValue) != 'number') alert('Please enter Numeric values.');
```

**EDIT**

I tried the below snippet but I still get an error.

```
var MaxValue= parseInt(document.getElementById('MV').value);
if (MaxValue > 9999999) 
    alert('The Max Value entered cannot be more than 10 million. Please verify the value entered.'); 
if (isNaN(MaxValue))
    alert('Please enter Numeric values.');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You need to convert your value into a number : `var MaxValue= +document.getElementById('MV').value;`

Comment: @Tushar -- I need some validations while entering values in a text box.
My code is below in the Answers section

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is what are you trying to do, look at this plunker  [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0szcFYAQmw2Ws8380MXJ?p=preview)

here is the function to do this validation.

```
    function evalExp() {
  var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
  var MaxValue = document.getElementById('MV').value;
  if (reg.test(MaxValue)) {
    if (parseInt(MaxValue) > 9999999) {
      alert("The Max Value entered cannot be more than 10 million. Please verify the value entered.");
    } else {
      alert("pass all validations");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Please enter Numeric values.");
  }
}
```

hope it helps